# How can I index recycle bin?

Tags: windows, windows-10, recycle-bin, search-indexing

How can I index recycle bin?

(There were so many instructions that I didn't ask and already know. So I edited everything out to focus on the subject.)

Comment: If you frequently need files there, don't delete them in the first place?

Comment: @grawity I use a software which delete files after some tasks. The files go to recycle bin.

Comment: @grawity And personally, I use recycle bin as a temp folder. I delete files, but sometimes I need it back afterwards. This method actually saved me 1 or 2 times.

Comment: I agree with Grawity. Don't use recyclebin if you work with files. If software deletes them to recyclebin, look into moving the files to a different folder instead.

Comment: @LPChip Thank you for your suggestion, but I still want to know. I will decide how to use.

Comment: @LPChip I didn't mention this because I thought it won't be necessary, but I'm not trying to restore the files. I'm trying to delete the files permanently. I'll add this to my question just in case.

Comment: The recycle bin doesn't work like a normal folder. Files inside are renamed and the original name and location are stored in a file, rather than NTFS. This explains why it takes so long to search. I have a feeling that you can't index it with windows. Maybe there is a third party app.

Comment: @mt025 Sounds like an answer. Thank you.

Comment: My recollection is that the recycle bin isn't a permanent place for deleted files.  When it's out of space it purges old trash to make room for new trash.  So it isn't safe to rely on it for potential recovery if you change your mind.  Moving files to your own folder rather than trash doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @fixer1234 I know that it is not a permanent place. And that's what I want to make use of it.

Comment: I use [Everything](http://voidtools.com/) to find files super quickly. No matter where they are on my hard drive or on the network. Did not find anything quicker to that day.

Comment: C:\$Recycle.Bin but even that isn't what it's supposed to be..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Everything](http://voidtools.com/) to find files by name immediately. As soon as the indexing process has finished you can type the filename you want and get the result immediately.

[image: Find files immediately]

It works on all recent Windows system I tested (starting with Windows 7), also on server systems where the indexing service is disabled sometimes.

Here is an overview from their own site:

> Locate files and folders by name instantly.
>
> - Small installation file
> - Clean and simple user interface
> - Quick file indexing
> - Quick searching
> - Minimal resource usage
> - Share files with others easily
> - Real-time updating

I personally use it on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that it's frustrating to be instructed on your use of things, especially when they seem to work for you. However I think there are a coupe of things you should know.

You mentioned that you want to permanently delete certain files. This is possible using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> - files deleted in this manner will skip the Recycle Bin, and simply "*be gone*".

As mentioned by others, the Recycle Bin is *not* something that you should *use* or *rely on* - it is a safety net. If you were to find yourself working on a networked computer, then it is crucially important to understand that ***there is no Recycle Bin*** for mapped network drives or network shares... files are immediately deleted. In some situations servers offer features to restore files, but again do not rely on or expect this.

Comment: I know that. I even mentioned `I know that files in the bin will be deleted permanently in FIFO manner. And that's what I want to make use of it.` I even backup using Dropbox. Please understand that I can't list everything I know and don't know. Please focus on the question.